# how to determine noise tolerance to use it in freeze detect filter in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, freeze

I'm trying to use freeze detect filter in ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i Trial.mp4 -vf "freezedetect=n=-60dB:d=0.5,metadata=mode=print:file=freeze.txt" -map 0:v:0 -f null -
```

Used the above command and output says no freeze. But the Video is a standstill video taken in mobile.

If I adjust the noise level to 0.05, there are freezes reported.

How to determine this value?

Answer (score 0):

You can determine this only by trial and error.

The filter calculates the difference between two frames as the ratio between their sum of absolute differences ([SAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences)). In pseudocode:

```
is_frozen(reference, frame) {
    sad = 0
    count = 0
    for plane in planes[frame] {
        sad += sad_of_plane(plane, reference, frame)
        count += width[plane] * height[plane]
    }
    ratio = sad / count
    return ratio <= noise
}
```

Since the actual difference between two frames is determined by its noisiness, it will be very content-dependent. Note that even if the subject did not change, “noise” could mean camera/sensor noise, which will always be different between two captured frames.

Only for computer-generated content the difference between frames with the same subject will be zero (or very close to zero).